# Honda 2002 Accord re-set after battery disconnect nightmare

Tags: honda, battery, audio, accord

I want to get my radio/car alarm re-set and I now have figured out my special code, but am I permanently locked out?

The farthest step that I get is to see the serial number (U XXXX and L xxxx, ), but I still see an Err1 code, so how  do I get to the CODE part so that I can enter the code?

I don't want to disconnect my battery, because it's a poor connection anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot disconnect the battery directly, take out the fuses which provide power to the radio and let the radio sit for the 30 minutes (or whatever is recommended). There should be two different fuses which provide power to the radio. One will be a switched source (for full power when the radio is being used) and another which is always-on (which provides power for when the car is off, to allow it to keep the codes/presets). If you pull these, it should reset the radio and allow you to get to the CODE screen.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your display reads ErrE you still input the radio code. The radio will simply count the number of times and I incorrect code has been input and display that on the screen. Code, Err1 through Err9 can all still have the code entered as an attempt. Only if the display reads ErrE you have to wait for the radio reset to be able to try again. Also to retrieve the code for your radio visit this site [Honda Radio Code](https://radio-navicode.honda.com) and enter the required information.